# Is it possible to fix a center reference point while dynamically generating range in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, yaxis

I couldn't find any information on this topic so I am looking for some assistance.

### Issue:

In ggplot it is easy to dynamically generate y axis upper and lower bounds with `scale_y_continuous`. However, dynamically generated bounds have their issues - especially when it comes to comparing data. Consider the instance where one would like to see a fixed range to make easy comparisons and not get misled by a visual with changing bounds. If I fix the ranges with the `scale_y_continuous(limits = c("lower bound", "upper bound"))` then I can run into issues with certain graphs not being visible for that fixed range.

### Question:

Is it possible to fix a center/focal point in a ggplot while dynamically generating the upper and lower bounds. For example, let's say that a certain graph extends from -10,000 to 5,000 and a second graph extends from -6,000 to 12,000 - to make this visual comparison easy I would like the center point to be stationary. So when I am cycling back and forth between graphs there is a point of reference.

Thus, I would like to fix a reference point of 0 to remain at the same center of the graphs while only extending the upper and lower bounds.

### Clarification:

Picture a coordinate plane with the origin at 0. If I were to draw a graph of x^2 for x:[-2,2] y:[4,4] and also x:[0,4] y:[0, 16] in order to easily compare the plots I would like to see the same window for both graphs as opposed to the second graph being zoomed into the first quadrant (positive plane) of the coordinate plane.

Is this possible? Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don' t think this is a ggplot issue. You could "center" them by saying something like limits=c(center -x,center+x), but that would still not allow for proper comparison. You might want to calculate the lowest and highest values of your entire data set and use those as limits. If you don't have too many factor levels consider facets, which fix (or don't) the axes for you.

Comment: You can use the `expand` argument in the scale to add whitespace to the axes, but you'd have to calculate the values.

Comment: Like Wave says, you can do `r = max(abs(range(data$y_axis_var)))` and use `limits = c(-r, r)`. That will center it at 0, but I don't see how this helps the comparison issue you describe. If all your data is in a `list` you can easily use an `sapply` to get the range of each, use max and min to get the extreme values, and then give all your plots the same scale.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
data = rbind(data.frame(x = -2:2, y = (-2:2)^2, f = 1),
             data.frame(x = 0:4, y = (0:4)^2, f = 2))

p = ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
    facet_wrap(~f) +
    geom_point()

p1 <- egg::symmetrise_scale(p, axis = 'x')
p2 <- egg::symmetrise_scale(p1, axis = 'y')
p2
```

[image]

Comment: I think this may be what I'm looking for - I will report back...EDIT:Unfortunately my company doesn't have the package egg and I am unable to install it on my own. Thank you for this suggestion but I will need to try another method.

Answer (score 0):

user9627008 's example makes more sense with free scales (rejected as an edit so reposted here):

```
p = ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
    facet_wrap(~f, scales="free") +
    geom_point()

p1 <- egg::symmetrise_scale(p, axis = 'x')
p2 <- egg::symmetrise_scale(p1, axis = 'y')
egg::ggarrange(p,p1,p2)
```

[image]